# InsertOrUpdate > Insert OK, Update not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

A few days a ago I tried AutMapper with Entity Framework Core, now I want to see how the `InsertOrUpdate` from `AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore` (v1.0.1) works.
But I can't bring it to up to work, here are my Test-classes / settings:

**DataContext (DbContext)**

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies(false).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(AppHelper.ShowDebugInfos).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking).UseSqlServer(AppHelper.ConnectionString);
    }

    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } // with some references to other tables
}
```

**Startup**

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();

services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase().AddDbContext<DataContext>(); // not sure if we need this for InsertOrUpdate

services.AddAutoMapper(automapper =>
{
    automapper.AddCollectionMappers();
    automapper.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<DataContext>(services);
    //automapper.SetGeneratePropertyMaps<GenerateEntityFrameworkCorePrimaryKeyPropertyMaps<DataContext>>(); // exception says we have to use UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel instead of this
}, typeof(DataContext).Assembly);
```

**AutoMapperProfile**

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    CreateMap<ContactTestDto, Contact>().ReverseMap();

    // did also try:
    //CreateMap<ContactTestDto, Contact>().EqualityComparison((source, destination) => source.Id == destination.Id);
    //CreateMap<Contact, ContactTestDto>().EqualityComparison((source, destination) => source.Id == destination.Id);
}
```

**Model Contact**

```
public partial class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // many more (including navigation properties)...
}
```

**Model ContactTestDto**

```
public partial class ContactTestDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    // nothing more
}
```

**Update**

```
// this makes no difference:
//Contact contactFromDb = db.Contacts.Find(1); // FirstName is "John"
//db.Entry(contactFromDb).State = EntityState.Modified;

// nothing happens:
db.Contacts.Persist(mapper).InsertOrUpdate(new ContactTestDto { Id = 1, FirstName = "Updated Name???" });

// insert ok:
db.Contacts.Persist(mapper).InsertOrUpdate(new ContactTestDto { FirstName = "Inserted Name" });

db.SaveChanges();
```

I can see the Select-Statements it **both** cases (via SQL Profiler), but on an update there are no updates sent, insert is fine. Also the `mapper` instance is working fine (I can map in both directions).

So, what did I wrong?

PS: Why I can't write "Hello SO-Community"? It will be cut down to "Community" oO

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled tracking in your db options (`.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)`), so you need either enable it back via options or enable it for such requests like this:

```
var currTracking = db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior;
try
{
    db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll;
    db.Contacts
        .Persist(mapper)
        .InsertOrUpdate(new ContactDto { Id = 1, FirstName = "Updated Name???" });
    db.Contacts.Persist(mapper).InsertOrUpdate(new ContactDto { FirstName = "Inserted Name" });
    db.SaveChanges();
}
finally
{
    db.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = currTracking;
}
```

P.S.
not sure that setting back to `currTracking` is needed via try-finally, but better safe than sorry.

Comment: Sometimes it's simple like this ;) I thought AutoMapper used an own comparison to create the sql statements (like the ```ProjectTo``` thing). With Tracking it works, thanks!